# Is it possible to fetch multiple column family/qualifier combinations in Bigtable through the Python API?

Tags: python, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I'm currently fetching multiple column qualifiers through the Bigtable Python API using filters, like:

`row_filters.ColumnQualifierRegexFilter("c1|c2")`

A column qualifier only needs to be unique within its column family though, so I would like to be able to use the same column qualifier in different column families, and only fetch the correct ones, e.g. say that families `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` contain the columns `c1`, `c2`, and `c3` but I just want `f1:c1,c2` and `f2:c3`.

I could do this just fine with cbt:
`cbt <...other args...> read columns="f1:c1,f1:c2,f2:c3"`

but if I just make a `RowFilterChain` with `FamilyNameRegexFilter("f1|f2")` and `ColumnQualifierRegexFilter("c1|c2|c3")` I'd get all the columns in both families.

Is there a way to specify column family and qualifier together in the API, or will I only be able to achieve this through column qualifiers that are unique throughout the whole table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch multiple combinations of filtered column families and column qualifiers, you'll need to combine [chain filters](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/using-filters#chain) and [interleave filters](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/using-filters#interleave).

For your example to query `f1:c1,f1:c2,f2:c3`, you would do something like this:

```
filter 1: Chain(column family f1, col  c1|c2)
filter 2: Chain(column family f2, col c3)

your filter: Interleave (filter 1, filter 2)
```

Using the Python client that will look like this:

```py
client = bigtable.Client(project=project_id, admin=True)
instance = client.instance(instance_id)
table = instance.table(table_id)

filter1 = row_filters.RowFilterChain(
    filters=[
        row_filters.FamilyNameRegexFilter("f1"),
        row_filters.ColumnQualifierRegexFilter("c1|c2")
    ]
)
filter2 = row_filters.RowFilterChain(
    filters=[
        row_filters.FamilyNameRegexFilter("f2"),
        row_filters.ColumnQualifierRegexFilter("c3")
    ]
)
rows = table.read_rows(
    filter_= row_filters.RowFilterUnion(
        filters=[
            filter1,
            filter2
        ]   
    )
)
```